# Maven dependency based on Eclipse Target Platform - Plug-in Development

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

While developing a plugin for eclipse 3.7.2 I have a dependency on refactoring.jar which will be part of the Target Platform - Plug-in Development. If the target platform changes, the version of the jar might change. As this specific version is not available on maven central repo nor any of our internal repos, I copied the jar to the project/lib dir and defined in pom.xml with dependency systemPath as the following.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.201-r372_v20111101-0700</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/refactoring-3.5.201-r372_v20111101-0700.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

It compiles the project and runs successfully on the target platform. But I would like to make the dependency independent of the version/target platform. Means it should always pickup the target platform version. Appreciate any suggestions on this.

Comment: One solution I could find is in parent pom add `code` <dependencyManagement> <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.201-r372</version>
   </dependency><dependencyManagement> `code` and in individual pom.xml add <dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>

Comment: One solution I could find is in parent pom add `<dependencyManagement> <dependency>
     <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.201-r372</version>
   </dependency></dependencyManagement>` and in individual pom.xml add `<dependency>
         <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId>
         <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId>
         <scope>provided</scope>
     </dependency>`

Answer (score 0):

By using dependency management this is some how simplified with changes in one place.

-----In paretn pom --------

```
`<dependencyManagement>
   <dependency> 
     <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId> 
     <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId> 
     <version>3.5.201-r372</version> 
  </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>`
```

------In individal pom files -----------

```
`<dependency> 
  <groupId>org.eclipse.ltk.core</groupId> 
   <artifactId>refactoring</artifactId> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
 </dependency>`
```